# Meaning of "thread the needle through" and "beat the devil's tattoo"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning, lyrics

Lyrics from the song, *Beat the Devil's Tattoo*:

> I thread the needle through, you beat the devil's tattoo.

Does anyone know the meaning of "thread the needle through" and "beat the devil's tattoo"?

Answer (score 3):

The webpage [Historically Speaking Beat The Devil’s Tattoo](https://idiomation.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/beat-the-devils-tattoo/) gives

> When you’re accused of beating the Devil’s tattoo, you’re being told that you are drumming on a hard surface with your fingers.  More often than not, it’s thought of a sign of impatience or ill-humour to be beating the Devil’s tattoo, but it need not be.  The saying, though seldom used these days, is still heard from time to time.

The website [Song Meanings](https://songmeanings.com/songs/view/3530822107858818952/) seems to imply that "thread the needle through" is probably a reference to heroin addiction.

Comment: For those unaware of the double meaning, the word *tattoo* in this sense originally meant a signal for soldiers to retire for the night, usually on drums or bugle, and is unrelated to *tattoo* meaning permanent inking below the skin. https://www.lexico.com/definition/tattoo

Answer (score 0):

Greybeards answer regarding beat the devil's tattoo is correct.

'I thread the needle through' simply means that he's the one demonstrating patience as threading a needle can be a difficult task.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Instead of commenting on another answer (that's for comments), you could support your own answer with sources.  Then you will be able to upvote others. 
 Please take a moment to [tour] the site and see the [help].